# query post limits

Tags: posts, filters, query-posts, limit

```
function posts_limit_fn($limit, $query, $custom_limit = ''){
    if($custom_limit !== ''){
        return $custom_limit;
    }
    return $limit;
}
```

this piece of code is executed into an AJAX function `add_action('wp_ajax_search_query', 'search_query');`

```
$queryString = array( 's' => $searchTerm, 'cat' => $categoriesIDs, 'post__not_in' => array($excludedPost));

if($queryString != ''){
    add_filter('post_limits', 'posts_limit_fn',10, 3);
    $custom_limit = 'LIMIT 0,4';
    apply_filters('post_limits', '', '', $custom_limit);

    $query = new WP_Query($queryString);
}
```

For some kinda of reasons the `apply_filters` doesn't work so the query is returning all posts. What would be the problem ?

UPDATE:

Seems that If I have something like this :

```
function posts_limit_fn($limit,$query,$custom_limit = ''){
    echo $custom_limit.">>>>>>>";
    if($custom_limit !== ''){
        return 'LIMIT 0,3';
    }
    return $limit;
}
```

the output is `LIMIT 0,4>>>>>>>>>LIMIT 0,10>>>>>>>>>post1,post2,post3`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If a moderator is somewhere around here, should I delete the first part of my post ?

Comment: $mylimit should be an int, and it's not related with the parameters the function uses.

Comment: If you're using query_posts I strongly recommend against it, and advise instead you make use of either get_posts or WP_Query ( all 3 use WP_Query internally )

Comment: You can edit your question if you like.

Comment: I updated my answer, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter for `add_filter` is the priority in which the filter is executed, the forth is the number of parameters the function in the second parameter uses.

The `wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits` function has an if that checks uses a couple of wordpress function to establish where in your page you are executing the code, in this case it's checking if it's in the frontend, if it's the main query and if it's in the search page.

The parameter `$limit` and `$query` are passed by the CMS, and those are default values, so if the conditions in the if aren't met, the function return the default `$limit`

edit:

```
function posts_limit_fn($limit, $query){
    return 'LIMIT 0, 3';
}
add_filter('posts_limit', 'posts_limit_fn',10, 2);
```

edit 2:

if you aren't going to use the parameters you can use the function like this:

```
global $custom_limit;
$custom_limit = '0, 2';
    function posts_limit_fn(){
            global $custom_limit
            return 'LIMIT ' . $custom_limit;
        }
add_filter('posts_limit', 'posts_limit_fn',10, 0);
```

That's one way to do it. Try to prefix all global vars, always, and if you can avoid them, better yet.

edit: without globals

```
function posts_limit_fn($limit, $query, $custom_limit = ''){
                if($custom_limit !== ''){
                    return $custom_limit;
                }
                return $limit;
            }
    add_filter('posts_limit', 'posts_limit_fn',10, 3);
$custom_limit = 'LIMIT 0,4';

apply_filters('posts_limit', '', '', $custom_limit)
```

**edit for `WP_Query`:**

If you are using `WP_Query`, for the pagination you can pass a `paged` parameter with each call to the function.

Comment: The filter name is `post_limits` but even if I change that, it doesn't work. Does the fact that I'm doing this into an AJAX call make this to not work ?

Comment: Check the updated question . What's strange is that if I replace `return $custom_limit` with `return 'LIMIT 0,3'` it's works.

Comment: @George02, if you are using a WP_Query, why not just add the `posts_per_page` parameter?

Comment: Because I'm doing this for an ajax widget. So first I want to show the first 5 results then at a button press to show the next 5. It's possible to do this with `post_per_page` ?

Comment: seems that calling `add_filter()` and then `apply_filters()` the function `posts_limit_fn` is called twice and in one of those 2 calls the `$custom_limit` is empty. What about that ?

Comment: You can pass a `paged` parameter with each call, to emulate pagination. or with offsets

Comment: I solved the problem using your idea. Edit your posts and I will mark it as accepted answer. Programmer being the question `Why that doesn't work ? still killing me` The only solution I found is that the `posts_limit_fn` is called twice once with filter applied once without. I posted on the official wordpress forum but ... they are not so nice as this community. Thank you for your time !